# unable to reach the root cause of exception

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

While trying to run a `jsp` page I get the following exceptions :

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it 
from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 17 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:644)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.22 logs.
```

Seeing these exceptions I unable to reach the root cause of it. Can anyone help me with it. My IDE doesn't show any red-marks that could indicate , that I am trying to compile a jsp that has errors. Instead it shows no signs of it.

*Note: Also I do not see the generated Java file, as the exception says*

*JSP Code:*

```
<%-- 
Document   : index
Created on : Dec 8, 2012, 10:55:43 AM
Author     : user
--%>

<%@page import="internet.CommunicationWithServer.PingTheServer"%>
<%@page import="java.util.GregorianCalendar"%>
<%@page import="internet.CommunicationWithServer.SendNodeInfo"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="internet.HelperClasses.*;" %>
<%@page import="General.HelperClasses.*;" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Client Nappster</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("css/index_css.css");
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<center> <h2 id="Head">Client Nappster</h2> </center>

<center> <h4 id="Head"><%= new GregorianCalendar().getTime().toString() %></h4> </center>

<%-- Call a method that checks for the internet connection --%>
<%! 
   boolean isConnectionAvailable;
   String networkIP;
%>
<% if(request.getAttribute("File-Sharing-Status") != null && ((Boolean)request.getAttribute("File-Sharing-Status")) == true) {%>
<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Success ! File shared with the nappster server"); </script>
<%}%>
<%
    isConnectionAvailable = new CheckConnection().checkConnection();
    if(isConnectionAvailable) {
        // send a message,the app is conneted to the nappster central server
        System.out.println("returned true");
        // call a method that sends the client's IP address to the nappster central server
        networkIP = new ClientAddress().getNetworkIP();
        // send to the server the address and the name of the node online
        boolean informationSent = new SendNodeInfo().sendInfo(networkIP);
        // call a method that starts a thread that after certain intervals checks if the node is still connected 
        // to the internet
        new PingTheServer().startPingThread();
        // make a 'Shared' Directory
        boolean directoryMade = new DirectoryMaker().makeDirectory(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"), "Shared");
        if(directoryMade == false) {
            //Warning : Unable to make a directory | Directory already exists
            System.out.println("Unable to create the 'Shared' directory | or directory already exists");
        }
    } else {
        // send an error message,unable to connect the app to the napster cental server
        System.out.println("returned false");
    }
%>

<jsp:include page="EmbeddedJSP/form_table.jsp" />

</body>
```

**EmbeddedJSP/form_table.jsp:**

```
    <%@page import="internet.CommunicationWithServer.QueryConnectedNodes"%>
    <%@page import="java.io.File"%>
    <%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
    <%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page import="General.HelperClasses.Stashed"%>
    <%@page import="internet.CommunicationWithServer.QueryFileNames"%>

    <%! String fileSharingStatusString; 
        Boolean fileSharingStatus;
        String nodesConnected;
        boolean ncStashed;
    %>

    <% BufferedReader sharingStatusReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + Constants.FilePaths.fstPath));
   while((fileSharingStatusString = sharingStatusReader.readLine()) != null) {
       fileSharingStatus = new Boolean(fileSharingStatusString.trim());
   }
    %>

   <% if(new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + Constants.FilePaths.nlPath).exists())
        ncStashed = true;
   %>

   <table width="100%" border="+3" id="Table_border_color">
    <tr>
        <th id="Nodes_Connected_Heading"> Nodes Connected </th>
        <th id="Files_to_be_shared_heading"> Select a File to share  </th>
        <th id="Files_shared_heading"> Files Shared  </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="20%" id="List_of_nodes_connected"> List <br />
            <%-- Get the list of all the nodes connected to the nappster server --%>
            <% if(new QueryConnectedNodes().getConnectedNodes() && ncStashed) {
                BufferedReader nodesConnectedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Constants.FilePaths.nlPath));
                String line;
                while((line = nodesConnectedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            %>
                    <%= line %>
            <%  } // end of while loop
              } // end of if block 
                  else {
            %>
            <em>No node connected to the nappster server !</em>
            <%}%>
        </td>
        <td width="60%" valign="top" align="center">  
            <form method="post" action="SendTheFileName" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div id="Files_to_be_shared"> 
                      <input type="file" id="File" name="FileTag" />
                      <input type="submit" value="Share" /> 
                    </div>
            </form>
        </td>

        <td id="List_of_files_shared">
            List of files shared. <br />
            <%-- check if the user has shared any file --%>
            <% if(fileSharingStatus.booleanValue()) {
                    // if true, get the name of the files
                    boolean requestSent = new QueryFileNames().getFileNames();
                    if(requestSent) {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + Constants.FilePaths.fsPath));
                        String line;
                        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             %>
                            <%= line %>
                            <br />

            <%
                        }
                    }                        
            } else {
            %>                
                <em>No file has been shared till now !</em>
                 <%}%>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you post your JSP code?

Comment: @Pradeep posted the code

Comment: @JimGarrison posted the code. I am working with netbeans 7.1

Comment: @KyelJmD posted the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolons :

```
<%@page import="internet.HelperClasses.*;" %>
<%@page import="General.HelperClasses.*;" %>
```

to

```
<%@page import="internet.HelperClasses.*" %>
<%@page import="General.HelperClasses.*" %>
```

In the generated *java file* the above snippet would be :

```
import internet.HelperClasses.*;;
import General.HelperClasses.*;;
```

You see, it will generate an error !

Answer (score 1):

The error message says "An error occurred at line: 17 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token" - you'll find the generated java file in tomcat's work directory and can typically identify the offending (matching) jsp line from the java code that tomcat generates.

You'll have to know that the way jsps are executed is, that they're compiled into a classic servlet, then to bytecode and executed as if they were written by you. As the error message applies to some code that was generated, you'll have to go into that code.

You have an extra superfluous ";" sign somewhere on your jsp file that generates an illegal java servlet - and that's what you'll find in the "work" directory

Comment: Are you working with a different tomcat directory - e.g. have you defined CATALINA_BASE? AFAIK tomcat by default generates code into the work directory - this might also be deactivated (I've never seen that) but most likely you're looking in the wrong directory

Comment: @saplingPro I think for this the server has to be running with the admin privileges. If the server is not running with admin privileges and is installed in _C:_ directory for example,then it won't be able to write the file